# Jquery set value of option element to be the text of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set the value attribute of the option element equal to the text of the option element itself. This is the code I have currently. For some reason it is concatenating the strings.

Here's the HTML markup.

```
    <select id="ResidentialBuildingType" name="ResidentialBuildingType">
     <option>SFD</option>
     <option>Test</option>
    </select>
```

Here's the jquery code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var select = $('#ResidentialBuildingType > option');
        $(select).each(function (index) {
            console.log(select.text());
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) receiver function to achieve that,

```
$('#ResidentialBuildingType > option').attr("value",function(){
  return $(this).text();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Zgh24/1251/)

Comment: I am indeed using the attr function. I just needed to get the text first.

Comment: @TarangHirani As per your question this is your requirement right..? I am confused.. can you brief what you need actually.?

Comment: @TarangHirani Yeah behind the screen, it will loop through the each option elements.. But for sure it would be better than our iteration..

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
console.log(select.text());
```

to

```
console.log($(this).text());
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg77/)

Comment: What was my original code doing initially? I am new to web and jQuery development.

Comment: well, instead of getting text of current object as in $(this), you were trying to use .text() in entire options array object as in $(select)